# I dont know how to use ForEach in this situation

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my app i am not sure how to correctly use ForEach loop.

Please write some text to input and press enter, task will be added to list. This is addNewTask() function. You can edit task by clicking edit icon but only once. I underestand why, because ForEach is in addNewTask(), okey, so, every task i can edit only once, if function is called. I think i need to create a function for this situation? But i dont know how to use it.

**var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-task');** in this variable are edit task icons.

If i try to use for example **editTask.addEvenetListener("click", function() { 
... })** output will be error because editask return nodelist. Any simple solution? I dont know what to do.

JS code start under this line -> **var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-task');**

```js
'use strict';

var todoTitle = document.querySelector('.title-input');
var todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');

function formatDate(date) {
    var monthNames = [
      "January", "February", "March",
      "April", "May", "June", "July",
      "August", "September", "October",
      "November", "December"
    ];
  
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();
  
    return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year + ', ' + hours 
+ ':' + mins;
}

function createNewTask(task) {
    var listItem = document.createElement('li');
    var textItem = document.createElement('div');
    var dateInfo = document.createElement('span');
    var icons = document.createElement('div');
    // var saveEditedTask = document.createElement('span');

var iconsClass = [
    '<i class="fas fa-tag"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-palette change-bgcolor"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-edit edit-task"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-check-square"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-task"></i>'
]

iconsClass.forEach(function(icon) {

    var iconParent = document.createElement('li');
    iconParent.className = 'icon-item';
    iconParent.innerHTML = icon;
    icons.appendChild(iconParent);
    
});

dateInfo.innerText = formatDate(new Date());
dateInfo.className = 'task-date';
textItem.className = 'list-content';
icons.className = 'action-icons';
textItem.innerText = task;
listItem.className = 'list-item';
// textItem.appendChild(icons);
listItem.appendChild(textItem);
// listItem.appendChild(saveEditedTask);
listItem.appendChild(icons);
listItem.appendChild(dateInfo);

return listItem;

};

function addNewTask() {
    var listItem = createNewTask(todoTitle.value);
    todoList.appendChild(listItem);
    todoTitle.value = '';

    var deleteTask = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-task');

    deleteTask.forEach(function (icon) {
        icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.closest("li.list-item").classList.add("hidden");     
        });
    });

    var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-task');

    editTask.forEach(function (icon) {
        icon.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var thisParent = 
    this.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
            thisParent.contentEditable = true;
            thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef";
            this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
            this.classList.add("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
        
            this.addEventListener("click", function () {
                thisParent.contentEditable = false;
                thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
                this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
                this.classList.add("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
            })
        })
    });

};

    todoTitle.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13 && todoTitle.value.length >= 1) {
            addNewTask();
        }
    });
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#todoapp {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

input.title-input {
    -webkit-transition: all.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
            transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

input.title-input:focus {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}


.todo-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
        -ms-flex-align: start;
            align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
            justify-content: flex-start;
}

.todo-list .list-item {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #202124;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /* min-heiglist-coht: 100px; */
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors {
    width: 105px;
    height: auto;
    /* height: 100px; */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);

    /* display: none; */
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors span {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    /* background-color: #ffffff; */
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors span:hover {
    border-color: #000000;
}

.todo-list .list-item:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.todo-list .list-item:hover .action-icons {
    opacity: 1;
}

.todo-list .list-item .list-content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.todo-list .list-item .task-date {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.todo-list .list-item .action-icons {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* opacity: 0; */
    -webkit-transition: all .25s;
    transition: all .25s;
}

.todo-list .list-item .action-icons .icon-item {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden { display:none !important; }

.visible { display: block !important; }

.fas.fa-check {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384- 
oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="todoapp">
    <input type="text" class="title-input" placeholder="Write a note..">
    <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: [ask] Please narrow down your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logic errors in your code.

Inside your **addNewTask()** function your executing the following code:

```
    var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-task');

    editTask.forEach(function (icon) {
..
}
```

That means every time a task is added every previous task gets it's click listeners and everything re-added.

Instead get a reference to the element that's actually using the class **edit-task** inside a newly generated task using:

```
var icon = listItem.getElementsByClassName("edit-task")[0];
```

This returns a HTML collection - which just consists of one element we're accesing using **[0]**.

The next problem is the way you're attaching the click event listeners anyway:

```
   editTask.forEach(function(icon) {
     icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
       var thisParent =
         this.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
       thisParent.contentEditable = true;
       thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef";
       this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
       this.classList.add("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");

       this.addEventListener("click", function() {
         thisParent.contentEditable = false;
         thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
         this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
         this.classList.add("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
       })
     })
   });
```

The above means every time you click the icon add another click listener. These interfere with each other and reset your textfield to be non editable.
Better do it like this:
Inside the **createNewTask()** function set the contentEditable property for the div **textItem** to false

```
textItem.contentEditable = false;
```

This way we can check this value inside the click event handler and act accordingly. If it's false make it true and vice versa.

```
  icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var thisParent =
      this.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    switch (thisParent.contentEditable) {
      case "false":
        thisParent.contentEditable = true;
        thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef";
        this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
        this.classList.add("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
        break;
      case "true":
        thisParent.contentEditable = false;
        thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
        this.classList.add("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
        break;
    }
  });
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
'use strict';

var todoTitle = document.querySelector('.title-input');
var todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');

function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var mins = date.getMinutes();

  return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year + ', ' + hours +
    ':' + mins;
}

function createNewTask(task) {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var textItem = document.createElement('div');
  var dateInfo = document.createElement('span');
  var icons = document.createElement('div');
  // var saveEditedTask = document.createElement('span');

  var iconsClass = [
    '<i class="fas fa-tag"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-palette change-bgcolor"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-edit edit-task"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-check-square"></i>',
    '<i class="fas fa-times-circle delete-task"></i>'
  ]

  iconsClass.forEach(function(icon) {

    var iconParent = document.createElement('li');
    iconParent.className = 'icon-item';
    iconParent.innerHTML = icon;
    icons.appendChild(iconParent);

  });

  dateInfo.innerText = formatDate(new Date());
  dateInfo.className = 'task-date';
  textItem.className = 'list-content';
  textItem.contentEditable = false;
  icons.className = 'action-icons';
  textItem.innerText = task;
  listItem.className = 'list-item';
  // textItem.appendChild(icons);
  listItem.appendChild(textItem);
  // listItem.appendChild(saveEditedTask);
  listItem.appendChild(icons);
  listItem.appendChild(dateInfo);

  return listItem;

}

function addNewTask() {
  var listItem = createNewTask(todoTitle.value);

  todoList.appendChild(listItem);
  todoTitle.value = '';

  var deleteTask = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-task');

  deleteTask.forEach(function(icon) {
    icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.closest("li.list-item").classList.add("hidden");
    });
  });

  var editTask = document.querySelectorAll('.edit-task');

  var icon = listItem.getElementsByClassName("edit-task")[0];

  icon.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var thisParent =
      this.parentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    switch (thisParent.contentEditable) {
      case "false":
        thisParent.contentEditable = true;
        thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#efefef";
        this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
        this.classList.add("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
        break;
      case "true":
        thisParent.contentEditable = false;
        thisParent.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
        this.classList.remove("fas", "fa-check", "fa-2x");
        this.classList.add("fas", "fa-edit", "edit-task");
        break;
    }
  });
};

todoTitle.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && todoTitle.value.length >= 1) {
    addNewTask();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#todoapp {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

input.title-input {
  -webkit-transition: all.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

input.title-input:focus {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.todo-list .list-item {
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #202124;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* min-heiglist-coht: 100px; */
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors {
  width: 105px;
  height: auto;
  /* height: 100px; */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  /* display: none; */
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors span {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  /* background-color: #ffffff; */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.todo-list .list-item .bg-colors span:hover {
  border-color: #000000;
}

.todo-list .list-item:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.todo-list .list-item:hover .action-icons {
  opacity: 1;
}

.todo-list .list-item .list-content {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.todo-list .list-item .task-date {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.todo-list .list-item .action-icons {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  -webkit-transition: all .25s;
  transition: all .25s;
}

.todo-list .list-item .action-icons .icon-item {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.visible {
  display: block !important;
}

.fas.fa-check {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384- 
oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="todoapp">
  <input type="text" class="title-input" placeholder="Write a note..">
  <ul class="todo-list"></ul>
</div>
```